# Secondary .htaccess file?

Tags: drupal

I was looking at the `apache2/ssl_error.log` and found an error relating to a secondary `.htaccess` file inside the `<drupal_root>/sites/default/files/civicrm/uploads` directory. Below is my stackoverflow post about the error, however, my question for here is this: is it normal to have a secondary `.htaccess` file within the civicrm files uploads directory or should I remove it? It only contains the following lines:

```
<Files "*">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287602/apache2-ssl-error-invalid-command-order

Even though I posted in stackover-flow, if anyone has any idea why I'm getting the this error, feedback would be greatly appreciated here or there, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This .htaccess file prevents files in this directory from being publicly downloadable. These files could be eg scans of membership forms or could contain other personal/identifiable data that you'll want to keep private;